# Unable to POST a task to Google Cloud Task Queue from Dataflow Job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-tasks

I'm having issues publishing an authenticated http task to a google cloud task queue from a dataflow job running in GCP. Each time I try, I get the following exception:

`io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission "iam.serviceAccount.actAs" for the resource "<service_account_1_email>"`

The issues is that service_account_1, is the same service account attached to the dataflow job, so it should not need actAs permissions -- it IS the service account.

The resources I am using are:
TemplatedDataflowJob(service_account_1)
CloudTaskQueue(service_account_2)
CloudFunctionV2(service_account_3; handles tasks from cloud task queue)

The flow I'm trying to perform is:
DataflowJob -> Task(has OICD token w/ handler CF as audience) -> CloudTaskQueue -> TaskQueueHandler

My user principal, service_account_1, and the default cf service account all have the enquerer permission on the task queue, and also have invoker permission on the handler CF and the Cloud run instance backing it

I've considered adding a pubsub topic, sending the message to that topic, triggering a cf off of that topic, and using the cf to enqueue the task, but I'm trying to avoid adding unnecessary resources to keep cost down.

I cannot try anything using a handler cf which allows unauthenticated traffic due to organizational policies.

I've tried:

- Using service_account_1, service_account_2, service_account_3, and the default cf service account as the service account to attach to the OICD token
- I've successfully enqueued a task from a separate cloud function running as the default cf service account
- I've successfully enqueued a task from my local using the flow above and using the default cf service account to build the OICD token (I don't want this as the ultimate solution because the default cf service account has too many permissions and would be insecure and ill advised in the production project)